# Proof for continuity of $\sqrt{x}$ - where's my mistake?

Tags: continuity, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I'm trying to prove that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$. Here's what I've got so far:

Consider $x_0 \in [0,\infty)$
$$|f(x) - f(x_0)| = |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x_0}|$$

Let's multiply that quantity by the positive number $|\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_0}|$. Then,
$$
\begin{align}
|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x_0}| &< |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x_0}||\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x_0}|\\
|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x_0}| &< |x-x_0| < \delta
\end{align}
$$

Let's pick $\delta=\epsilon$. Now we have
$$
\begin{align}
|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x_0}| &<\delta \\
|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x_0}| &<\epsilon \\
|f(x) - f(x_0)| & < \epsilon
\end{align}
$$
When $|x-x_0|<\delta$. Seems proven if you ask me, but from what I've read, the modulus of continuity of $\sqrt{x}$ is $\delta(\epsilon)=\epsilon^2$. This forces me to conclude that I've made a mistake somewhere, but I can't find it. (I bet it's some dumb detail)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Multiplying by a positive number on the RHS doesn't mean the inequality holds. $1<2$ but $1\nless 0.1\cdot 2$.

Comment: Try showing $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}|^2<\varepsilon^2$.  The triangle inequality should be useful.

Comment: @tomasliam And that's my dumb mistake! Of course, $|\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_0}|$ isn't necessarily greater than 1. Can you add your comment as an answer? I'd like to accept it.

Comment: Remember that $\;\sqrt{x_0}\;$ is a constant number... In case $\;x_0=0\;$ then you can consider $\;\sqrt x-\sqrt{0}=\sqrt x<1\;$ since $\;x\;$ will be close to zero (and in this case there is only continuity from the right side). Otherwise as shown in my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$|\sqrt x-\sqrt{x_0}|=\frac{|x-x_0|}{\sqrt x+\sqrt{x_0}}<\frac\delta{\sqrt x+\sqrt{x_0}}$$

and you know $\;\sqrt x\ge 0\;$ for all $\;x\in[0,\infty)\;$ , so $\;\sqrt x+\sqrt{x_0}\ge\sqrt{x_0}\;$ ...